# iPad App: Keep getting this error 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am fairly new to objective c so this might seem like a stupid question but would appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem.

I keep getting this in my terminal

> 2013-03-11 19:34:41.658 ColourPattern[380:c07] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'MainView.xib''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x190c012 0x168fe7e 0x190bdeb 0x7f2fac 0x7f498d 0x5d6ceb 0x5d7002 0x5d5ed6 0x5e7315 0x5e824b 0x5d9cf8
>   0x2774df9 0x2774ad0 0x1881bf5 0x1881962 0x18b2bb6 0x18b1f44 0x18b1e1b
>   0x5d57da 0x5d765c 0x22bd 0x21f5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called
>   throwing an exception (lldb)

And in my main class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

I keep getting thread 1:signal SIGABRT beside this line - int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

My application loads up but only show a black screen, I had it working at one point and can't figure this out why it isn't working now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MainView.xib in your list of files?  Did it get deleted?  The error is being generated because it can't find MainView.xib.

Comment: It is there, i even tried removing and adding it again but didn't work. I don't understand why it can't find that file

Comment: Click on your project name then select 'target' and on the right select 'Build Phases.'  Under 'Copy Bundle Resources' makes sure you see `MainView.xib`.  If not, click the '+' sign in the group to add it.

Comment: í have done that and it is in there, i have even removed it and added it again

Answer (score 0):

Turn off auto-layout or run the app in iOS 6.